# Look up to him, who is he?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, literature

> Born on the first soil, aiming for the next
>   Stolen as replacement, his life a lie
>   To be loved, serve but never die
>   Death came in a flash, lost mother
>   Hideous rictus, fear and darkness
>   Insanity lurking in the water
>   A mirror to his own madness
>   Four were in fact five
>   Then five were four again
>   To be the first, leave none alive
>   Now only war will reign
>   Burning sacrifice, deceptive bait
>   To live on the edge for a century wait
>   A ghost to be revealed, reborn on the second soil

*EDIT:*
I posted this question after seeing several riddles about half-famous books (some may know them, some may not), and tried mine. If it's not from a hugely known series of books, it has still won some awards and the author definitely has some popularity (at the very least he lives off of writing). Of course, if you don't know it... then you can't answer. Still, here is a **hint:**

> He is from a series of hard SF novels from a british author.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Mars rovers?

Comment: No, but I wonder what make you think that ^^

Comment: @Keelhaul does this have any relation to comics?

Comment: @David Foong Nope, purely literature

Comment: Is it "Barry Allen" - some of it fits...

Comment: Not either (15 char)

Comment: might want to add hints? reading this makes me think of plots of Supernatural...

Comment: Needs hints now. 246 views and up for nearly 2 months, no-one has it.

Comment: OK, I added a hint ;)

Comment: From your previous question, this is certainly a Lovecraft story... but I'm unfamiliar with the stories.

Comment: @tyobrien I disagree, because he speaks of the author in present tense, and I'm not sure lovecraft was hard sf.

Comment: Is this hard SF series made by one author or two?

Comment: @ShaneHsu One author

Comment: Is [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189246/31394) cheating?

Comment: Since you didn't use it to answer here, it's OK (and this riddle needed an answer anyway)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rand 'alThor [posted the question on SciFi stack exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189246/what-series-of-hard-sf-novels-is-this-riddle-describing). My answer:

Look up to him

> This is a play on his name, Sky Haussmann, from **Alastair Reynolds' Revelation Space** novels. Sky is the protagonist/antagonist of "Chasm City", but he also makes a cameo appearance a century later in "Redemption Ark".

Born on the first soil, aiming for the next

> Sky Haussmann is on a generation ship fleet heading for another planet.

Stolen as replacement, his life a lie

> Ostensibly Titus Haussman's son, it's later revealed that he was secretly adopted after the real son died.

To be loved, serve but never die

> He's ships crew and immortal.

Death came in a flash, lost mother

> One of the generation ships blew up, killing his mother.

Hideous rictus, fear and darkness

> OK, this one I'm not entirely sure about. A lot of the novel was set against a background of paranoia and fear.

Insanity lurking in the water

> The novel features a psychotic dolphin!

A mirror to his own madness

> The dolphin's madness reflects Sky's.

Four were in fact five

> There were four ships in the generation fleet, but there was a legend of a fifth ship some light days behind. This turned out to be true.

Then five were four again

> One ship blew up.

To be the first, leave none alive

> Late in the novel Sky, now captain, wanted to be the first to reach the target planet. To lighten the ship, and hence make it able to cruise for longer before having to slow down, he jettisoned his entire cargo of cryo frozen colonists.

Now only war will reign

> Understandably, the other ships' colonists were a little miffed at this ruthless slaughter and waged war against Sky and his followers, who are now his cultists.

Burning sacrifice, deceptive bait

> Sky is captured and put to death, but he'd anticipated this and left a stooge to be executed in his place.

To live on the edge for a century wait

> To conceal his fake death, he goes into cryosleep for a century under the care of his cultists.

A ghost to be revealed, reborn on the second soil

> At the end of "Chasm City" his fake death and survival is revealed

Comment: Mostly good, well done ;). "Hideous rictus, fear and darkness" is directly related to the "lost mother" event. "Now only war will reign" is more related to the fate of the planet in question, and can you explain the "Burning sacrifice" ?

Comment: @Keelhaul I'm afraid not. I read the book over a decade ago and have lent it out to someone since. Most of the rest of my answer was from memory, except the secret adoption bit which I confirmed on a wiki. Feel free to edit my answer with any additional detail you think fit.